# QLabel consuming too much space

Tags: qt, qt4

I use a QLabel and QPLineEdit within a QStackedWidget , the QLable should be nearly the size of the window holding this widget.

But when I set a extra long text to QLabel , it's expanding too much , and I'm not able to reduce the window size horizontally , the minimum width was too much.

I set the size policy of these three widgets to `Minimum` already ,  it just won't work for me.

**UPDATE**

maybe it's better saying like this:  how to let QLabel display part of the text , when there's not enough space

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
  #include <QtGui>

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) 
{
    QApplication app (argc , argv);

    QWidget w;
    QLabel *label = new QLabel ("Very very very long text");
    label->setSizePolicy (QSizePolicy::Minimum , QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QVBoxLayout layout (&w);
    layout.addWidget ( label );
    w.show();
    return  app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you give your label a maximum width?

Comment: @Mat it's like a IM window , i don't want users get a large "minimum width" of that application

Comment: Yes, so why don't you set a maximum width for that label?

Comment: @Mat , but when the window is resized , i want QLabel to display more

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant parts of your code. If you're using simple layouts, the parent widgets shouldn't grow when you add text to your label - at least that's not happening on a simple test here.

Comment: I take it you don't want word wrapping?

Comment: @Troubadour no , just single line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the simplest thing to do is simply to ignore that label's horizontal size hint.
As long as you have other widgets in there (or force a minimum width manually to the container), this should do what you want:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLabel *l1 = new QLabel("This very long text doesn't influence "
                            "the width of the parent widget");
    l1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    // Style just to make it clear that the widget is 
    // being resized to fit the parent, it doesn't "overflow"
    l1->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
    l1->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
    l1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

    QLabel *l2 = new QLabel("This influences the width");
    l2->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
    l2->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&w);
    layout.addWidget(l1);
    layout.addWidget(l2);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```