# PyQt how to maintain Layout Stretch ratio

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm creating an app for sports stats. I am having trouble rendering the stats nicely. Check image below.

[image]

I would like the display to resemble a tabular-like format. The labels in blue have their parents' layout stretch values set to 1 but when a name is too long, the stretch is obviously not respected. I tried using elided label but there is no effect.

So question is, is there a way to maintain the layout stretch of widgets in a layout without having to set fixed or minimum sizes.

ui for the items in the scrollarea

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Item</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Item">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>666</width>
    <height>50</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777215</width>
    <height>16777215</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">/*
    primary-background: #24212b
    accent-bg1: #3b3646
    accent-bg2: #423d4f
    button-bg: #4c465b
    button-hover-gb: #af5694
    button-disabled-bg: #3e3a4b
    button-disabled-fg: #615b75
    border-color: #454053

    fg-blue: #90c4f9
    fg-orange: #f09449
    button-bg: #90c4f9
*/

* {
    background-color: #3b3646;
    color: #adadad;
    border: 0px solid #454053;
}

#central_widget {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#widget_time_display QLabel {
    font: 9pt &quot;Calibri&quot;;
}

#widget_odds_display QLabel {
    font: 9pt &quot;Cambria Math&quot;;
}

#widget_time_display QLabel, #widget_odds_display QLabel {
    color: #c19652;
}

#widget_teams_display QLabel, #widget_tournament_display QLabel {
    font: 9pt &quot;Consolas&quot;;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6b95ba;
}

QPushButton {
    background-color: #564f66;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #af5694;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #964a7f;
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: #3e3a4b;
    color: #615b75;
}

#line, #line_1, #line_2, #line_3, #line_4, #line_5 {
    max-width: 1px;
    background-color: #565068;
}</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget" native="true">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="0,0,1,0,0">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_time_display" native="true">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>8</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>8</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>8</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_time">
           <property name="text">
            <string>20:30</string>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_date">
           <property name="text">
            <string>8 Jun</string>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="Line" name="line">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3" stretch="1,0,1">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_teams_display" native="true">
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="ElidedLabel" name="label_home_team">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Home Team Name</string>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="ElidedLabel" name="label_away_team">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Away Team Name</string>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="Line" name="line_3">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_tournament_display" native="true">
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="ElidedLabel" name="label_tournament">
              <property name="text">
               <string>League/Tournament Name</string>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="ElidedLabel" name="label_category">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Category/Country/Region Name</string>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_odds_display" native="true">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_4" native="true">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Ignored">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
               <property name="spacing">
                <number>8</number>
               </property>
               <property name="leftMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="topMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="rightMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="bottomMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>H</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_home_odd">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>2.97</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_5" native="true">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Ignored">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
               <property name="spacing">
                <number>8</number>
               </property>
               <property name="leftMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="topMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="rightMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="bottomMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>X</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_draw_odd">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>2.97</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_6" native="true">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Ignored">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
               <property name="spacing">
                <number>8</number>
               </property>
               <property name="leftMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="topMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="rightMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <property name="bottomMargin">
                <number>0</number>
               </property>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>A</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="away_odd">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>2.97</string>
                 </property>
                 <property name="alignment">
                  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="Line" name="line_4">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_actions" native="true">
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>8</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="button_find_stats">
              <property name="cursor">
               <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string/>
              </property>
              <property name="iconSize">
               <size>
                <width>16</width>
                <height>16</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLabel" name="label_stats_collected">
              <property name="text">
               <string>DONE</string>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>ElidedLabel</class>
   <extends>QLabel</extends>
   <header>spa.custom_widgets.elided_qlabel</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

the elided label

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPainter, QFontMetrics

class ElidedLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text='', elide_mode: Qt.TextElideMode = Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.elide_mode = elide_mode
        # self.setWordWrap(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        elided_text = metrics.elidedText(self.text(), self.elide_mode, rect.width())
        painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft, elided_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import threading, time
    app = QApplication([])
    label = ElidedLabel("This is a long text that should be el")
    label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font: 10pt 'Lucida Console'}")
    label.show()
    def change_text():
        time.sleep(10)
        label.setText("This is a long text that should be elided at the end if it exceeds the width of the label.")
    threading.Thread(target=change_text, daemon=True).start()
    app.exec()
```

Edit:
My question was never about QLabel, it was about Layout Stretch but reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470603/qlabel-consuming-too-much-space) was helpful. I changed the horizontal `QSizepolicy` of my affected Labels to `Ignored` and everything works as I required. Long text is elided when necessary.

Output:
[image]

Comment: The ElidedLabel only *shows* a shorter text, its space requirements remain the same for the full text set. Change the horizontal size policy of the labels to `Ignored` (or set it for the custom class, if you're using widget promotion). Also, ***NEVER*** use threading to directly access UI elements, as they are not thread safe: trying to do so is dangerous and potentially fatal. If you want to delay a function call, use [`QTimer.singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html#singleShot-4): change to `QTimer.singleShot(10000, change_text)` and remove `time.sleep`.

Comment: Thanks! I Changed the size policy and worked as I required. About threading, I normally don't use the threading module when dealing with PyQt. That was the simplest way I could think of to test the 'elison' effects but I appreciate the advice!

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using threading, but it *must* be use properly. The only correct and safe way to do so in Qt (at least, when dealing with objects that aren't thread safe) is by using signals, and that's why QTimer is the perfect candidate for these situations, since it doesn't need to use threads at all.